# ssis warning package contains data flow components with multiple inputs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

While using SQL Server Integration Services I get the warning:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The package contains data flow components with
multiple inputs. Run-time dependencies that exist among these components may
increase memory usage and reduce performance. Consider removing the dependency
chain for the following component IDs and output IDs: 382(419) , to improve
performance.
```

This is just one; I think I receive 4 of these in the last Data Flow I executed, containing different IDs.

I read somewhere that there is no way to 'search' for IDs, so I went through the whole Data Flow by hand, looking at all the components and underlying in-/output components. A few IDs I found, but most I did not. This makes it difficult to troubleshoot, let alone understand this warning. I cannot find anything concerning this issue on Stackoverflow are anywhere else on the web.

Update: I went through the XML Code of the package (right-click the package.dtsx => View Code || Menu:View => Code || F7) but the IDs are not listed there. Excerpt:

```
<outputs>
                <output
                  refId="Package\Sequence Container A\Data Flow A\Data Flow Source A.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]"
                  name="OLE DB Source Output">
                  <outputColumns>
                    <outputColumn
                      refId="Package\Sequence Container A\Data Flow A\Data Flow Source A.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[AABB]"
                      codePage="1252"
                      dataType="str"
                      errorOrTruncationOperation="Conversion"
                      errorRowDisposition="FailComponent"
                      externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Sequence Container A\Data Flow A\Data Flow Source A.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].ExternalColumns[AABB]"
                      length="18"
                      lineageId="Package\Sequence Container A\Data Flow A\Data Flow Source A.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[AABB]"
                      name="AABB"
                      truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" />
```

Can someone explain what this warning means, how to find IDs, and how to "remove the dependency chain".

Thanks.

Comment: You can search the XMLA (code-view) for the IDs.

Comment: How do I do that? I looked at the code for the Package.dtsx, but I could not find any IDs in there that made sense or any relevant hits on the IDs in the warning (382 for instance). Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a 2014 server to play with, but it seems that your xmla format is very different from mine.   I'm going to leave my answer up in case it helps other people with older versions of SQL Server/SSIS.

Comment: I have received this warning more then once. Resolving it was either unnecessary or did not decrease execution time.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your package open in Visual Studio, you can pull down the View menu, and click "Code".   This will take you to the XMLA code that is your package.

The ID's are the ID properties of the various xml elements in the code.   Here is some sample code from one of my packages:

```
<output id="122" name="OLE DB Destination Error Output" description="" exclusionGroup="1" synchronousInputId="121" deleteOutputOnPathDetached="false" hasSideEffects="false" dangling="false" isErrorOut="true" isSorted="false" errorOrTruncationOperation="" errorRowDisposition="NotUsed" truncationRowDisposition="NotUsed"><outputColumns>
<outputColumn id="123" name="ErrorCode" description="" lineageId="123" precision="0" scale="0" length="0" dataType="i4" codePage="0" sortKeyPosition="0" comparisonFlags="0" specialFlags="1" errorOrTruncationOperation="" errorRowDisposition="NotUsed" truncationRowDisposition="NotUsed" externalMetadataColumnId="0" mappedColumnId="0"/>
<outputColumn id="124" name="ErrorColumn" description="" lineageId="124" precision="0" scale="0" length="0" dataType="i4" codePage="0" sortKeyPosition="0" comparisonFlags="0" specialFlags="2" errorOrTruncationOperation="" errorRowDisposition="NotUsed" truncationRowDisposition="NotUsed" externalMetadataColumnId="0" mappedColumnId="0"/></outputColumns><externalMetadataColumns isUsed="False"/></output>
</outputs>
</component>
<component id="196" name="Script Component" componentClassID="{2E42D45B-F83C-400F-8D77-61DDE6A7DF29}" description="Executes a custom script." localeId="-1" usesDispositions="false" validateExternalMetadata="True" version="4" pipelineVersion="0" contactInfo="Executes a custom script.;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SqlServer v10; © 2007 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;4">
<properties>
<property id="200" name="SourceCode"
```

You can use ctrl-F to search this code.   I would start off looking for `id="382"` and `id="419"`

Comment: Thanks for answering, Tab. Sadly, I did that and there are no `<output id`, `<component id`, or `<property id` to be found. Also, `id="3` does not give any result. I am using SSIS 2014, if that helps.

Comment: Can you add the xmla code of your package to your question?

Comment: I added an excerpt; all code might be a bit too much. But there is no code like yours. It's like they decided that strings is good enough for the XMLA code, but not for Error/Warning messages.

Comment: I can't imagine how the error message could generate an id, if the id isn't in the XMLA, but unfortunately I don't have SQL 2014 to experiment with.